# Object Mapper configuration not working for nested objects from thirdparty libraries in Springboot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, json-serialization, nested-object

I have a srping-boot application which is returning a nested object as below:
here the `time_to_ship` nested object is coming from a third-party-jar and the `"name"`
object is coming from an internal model object.the `"name"` object is anotated with `"@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)"` . So in the `"name"` object its null fields are ignored. but since the `"time_to_ship"` is being taken from a third-party-library and is not annotated. the application is not ignoring its null fields.

I have configured the global objects mapper bean to ignore any fields which are `null` through the below bean config:. however it doesn't seem to have any effect. Also i have tried to configure porperty in the application.properties file:    `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL`, but this also doesn't work

```
  @Configuration
    public class ObjectMapperConfig{
        @Bean
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
         mapperBuilder) {
          return mapperBuilder.build().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL).setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY); 
          
        }
      
    }
```

sample response object below

```
{
        "id": "5117b9ba-60a2-4d0a-bd0a-58217fb96791",
        "relationalElements": {
            "PRNT": {
                "757b332e-3a88-4759-a1ca-9d9e8e9e38ca": {
                    "id": "757b332e-3a88-4759-a1ca-9d9e8e9e38ca",
                    "_class": "org.ondc.caas.elements.model.metadata.ProductTypeMetadata"
                }
            }
        },
        "parentId": "757b332e-3a88-4759-a1ca-9d9e8e9e38ca",
        "createdDate": 1682598703676,
        "updatedDate": 1682598573705,
        "status": "Draft",
        "seqId": 91,
        "_class": "org.ondc.caas.elements.model.Product",
        "fields": {
            "time_to_ship": {
                "id": "319acc1b-1cdb-4eae-a978-c391caa5860d",
                "name": "time_to_ship",
                "type": null,
                "coreType": null
            },
            "name": {
                "id": "e42dce97-c12e-4105-9783-5d44b83675ca",
                "name": "name",
                "_class": "org.ondc.caas.elements.model.CaasField"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have configured the ojbect mapper bean to ignore any fields which are null through the below bean config: